# vb.net Server error in '/' application after checking out latest version of repo

Tags: vb.net, svn, compiler-errors, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm working on a vb.net application, and have just finished implementing a new feature.

The branch that I was working on was a few commits behind production, so although the feature works correctly on my branch, I wanted to update my local repository to the latest version of the code, and then check that my new feature still works before committing it.

My company are using TortoiseSVN as their version control software- I have predominantly been using Git for the last 10 years, so am pretty unfamiliar with SVN.

To update my local repository to get it in line with the most recent release of the code, I right clicked on my branch folder, and clicked 'SVN Update'. After the update had run, the output stated that there was a conflict in the `.vbproj` file- where the differences were highlighted, I selected to use the version from the central repository- so that I would have the code from the most recent version now used on my local branch.

However, after doing this, when I now try to run the application locally, although it does run, when I try to navigate to the page where the feature that I have just implemented is, the browser now returns an error page, which says:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Compilation Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: BC30389: 'editcompany' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File: C:\ ...\editcompany.aspx.b5c3c836.jqph2fmj.0.vb    Line: 42

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

Is this happening because of the merge conflict that I had with the `.vbproj` file? If so, how can I resolve this? Or, if not, what's causing the error?

I don't understand the compiler error message:

> is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'.

None of the classes in my project are declared as a `Friend`...

**Edit**

The file that it's complaining about appears to be a compiled file, but when I looked for it in the path that the error message specifies, it doesn't seem to be there- I'm guessing it's one that's generated during compile time, and is removed when the application is stopped/ no longer running?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what the issue was: in my .aspx file for the page where the feature I had added in my branch, I had set `Inherits="App.editcompany"`. Removing this seems to have resolved the problem.